# How to use CardView getCardBackgroundColor correctly

Tags: android-cardview

I am trying to compare CardView background color with color from my global colors (from colors.xml).

```
if (cardView1.getCardBackgroundColor() == ContextCompat.getColor(getApplication(), R.color.grayLighter))
```

cardView1.getCardBackgroundColor return ColorStateList and not int,
and I cant use getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() because the button don't have the default color.

Thank you for your help